# I can't capture the image from Google Maps using the coordinates

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

There was a minor issue during execution, which seems to be related to the incompatibility between the ChromeDriver and Google Chrome. However, I've checked, and both are updated and correct. Can you tell me if there's any issue in the code? Is there something I should add?

Code(Python):

`from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def capture_google_maps(latitude, longitude, zoom=15, filename='map_screenshot.png'):
options = Options()
options.binary_location = 'C:\Users\User\Downloads\Apps\drives\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe'

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = f"https://www.google.com/maps/@{latitude},{longitude},{zoom}z"

driver.get(url)

driver.maximize_window()

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.save_screenshot('C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\PY\\ProjectsFreela\\RastreamentoWeb\\webScraping_02\\map_screenshot.png')

driver.quit()
```

latitude = 37.7749
longitude = -122.4194

capture_google_maps(latitude, longitude)`

I hope to successfully create the capture file in the desired directory.